# How do I create an android application that takes in numbers in pairs, multiplies them, and adds the result?

Tags: android, math, calculator

Until three weeks ago I knew nothing about developing applications for android, and with very basic Java background.

However, I took up the interest, and I'm now tying to develop a simple application that performs basic arithmetic operations.

What I would like the application to do is take in figures input by the user, up to 20 pairs, multiply each pair separately, and then add the results.
I have gotten through the multiplication of the pairs, but can't get onto adding up the results.
This is what I have so far for the multiplication part, and it works okay....

```
public class CalcAlgorithm extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final String LOG_TAG = "MainScreen";
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.calc_algorithm);

    final EditText value1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.value1);
    final EditText value2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.value2);
    final EditText value3=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.value3);
    final EditText value4=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.value4);
    final EditText value5=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.value5);
    final EditText value6=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.value6);
    final EditText value7=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.value7);
    final EditText value8=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.value8);
    final EditText value9=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.value9);
    final EditText value10=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.value10);
    final TextView result=(Button) findViewById (R.id.multiplyValues);
    final TextView result2=(Button) findViewById (R.id.multiplyValues2);
    final TextView result3=(Button) findViewById (R.id.multiplyValues3);
    final TextView result4=(Button) findViewById (R.id.multiplyValues4);
    final TextView result5=(Button) findViewById (R.id.multiplyValues5);
    final TextView result6=(Button) findViewById (R.id.addButton);

    Button multiplyButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.multiplyValues);
    multiplyButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                int val1=Integer.parseInt(value1.getText().toString());
                int val2=Integer.parseInt(value2.getText().toString());
                Integer answer = val1*val2;
                result.setText(answer.toString());
            }  catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Failed to multiply numbers",e);
            }
        }  
    });

     Button multiplyButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.multiplyValues2);  
       multiplyButton2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
           public void onClick(View v) {  
              try {
                   int val3 = Integer.parseInt(value3.getText().toString());  
                   int val4 = Integer.parseInt(value4.getText().toString());
                   Integer answer = val3 * val4;  
                   result2.setText(answer.toString());                     
               }  catch (Exception e) {
                   Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Failed to multiply numbers",e);
               }
           }  
       });  

       Button multiplyButton3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.multiplyValues3);  
       multiplyButton3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
           public void onClick(View v) {  
              try {
                   int val5 = Integer.parseInt(value5.getText().toString());  
                   int val6 = Integer.parseInt(value6.getText().toString());  
                   Integer answer = val5 * val6;  
                   result3.setText(answer.toString());  
           }  catch (Exception e) { Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Failed to multiply numbers",e);}}  
       });  

       Button multiplyButton4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.multiplyValues4);  
       multiplyButton4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
           public void onClick(View v) {  
              try {
                   int val7 = Integer.parseInt(value7.getText().toString());  
                   int val8 = Integer.parseInt(value8.getText().toString());  
                   Integer answer = val7 * val8;  
                   result4.setText(answer.toString());  
           } catch (Exception e) { Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Failed to multiply numbers",e);}} 
       });  

       Button multiplyButton5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.multiplyValues5);  
       multiplyButton5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
           public void onClick(View v) {  
              try {
                int val9 = Integer.parseInt(value9.getText().toString());
                int val10 = Integer.parseInt(value10.getText().toString());  
                   Integer answer = val9 * val10;  
                   result5.setText(answer.toString());  
           } catch (Exception e) {
               Log.e(LOG_TAG,"Failed to multiply number",e);
           }
           }
       });
```

Is this the right path? And, i realize that there is a way of summarising the code into fewer lines and not as i have it. Could someone please show me how I can go about having fewer lines of code, and then adding up the results all at once? 
After adding the values, I'd again like to perform some more (basic) operations on the results, but i think after I have known how to add the results, I should be able to figure my way from there.
**Perhaps i should point out that i would require the addition to be done once separately i.e on clicking of an added button (TotalSum,maybe) separately and not progressively as the multiplication goes on, such that the user can see the multiplied results for each pair of figures entered, and the total of all paired results on clicking  a separate button..
It would also be of immense help if i could get links to some books/documentation/videos that could help with arithmetic functions in writing android applications.
Any help will be greatly appreciated guys. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, here is the solution.

Create a class variable like `private int total=0;` and in each `setOnClickListener` add your `answer`s to this variable.

```
Integer answer = val1*val2;
total += answer;
```

Also instead of using 5 `Button` and 10 `TextView`s you can do this with simply one `Button` and one `TextView` storing results in another `TextView` but you said you are practicing, if it is just to practice it should be alright.

Comment: the solution you suggest would add the multiplied results one at a time as they become available, right? I'd like for them to be added all at once after the multiplication of the pairs has been completed, such that a user on the UI can see both the multiplied results, and ultimately, the added results.  Could you please see if you can help with that?  And, about the having one button and one TextView storing results part, how do i achieve that?

Comment: Ok then don't print `total` to screen. Print it after last button clicked. Your last button is `Button5` I guess, inside `onClick` method of this button, print your total to screen. For example `results.setText(total.toString());`

Comment: If you want to use one button and two `EditText, create an `ArrayList` of `Integer`. Like this: `ArrayList<Integer> results = new ArrayList<Integer>();`
You will have one `Button` and inside `onClick` method of this button, calculate multiplication and push it to array list `results.add(answer)`. After that clean your boxes, `value1.setText("");` and `value2.setText("");`. At the and you can put a for loop for your `ArrayList` and calculate summation and print it to screen.

Comment: But you need to decide how you will end getting answer. You can put a counter and set it to a number, like 10 or 20, or you can put another Submit button and tell user to click button when they finish entering numbers.

Comment: thanks @Gokhan Arik for the detailed info on arrays, i will look into that....i appreciate it...meanwhile, however, i managed to get a way of having the code perform the desired operation, but got stuck when i tried to perform further operations... So i think i will work on having a fully functional code first, before looking into the array part ..i am posting another question, an extension of sorts from this one, please look it up and see if you could help with that too..

Comment: No problem, find Android tutorials on this page and try watching this videos, it will be helpful if you just started. Watch and try write code with him at the same time, if u just watch you will learn nothing : [thenewboston](http://thenewboston.org/tutorials.php)

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `calculateResultSum()` method, which you call at the end of each onClick method with does something like

```
void calculateResultSum() {
    Integer res1 = Integer.parse(result.getText.toString());
    // .. get all the other results
    Integer finalResult = res1 + res2 + res2 + res4 + res5;
    //do something with the result
}
```

BUT your approach is very redundant, i.e. you have the same code in all of you onClick methods. This is considered bad code style, you should try to extract the actual processing of the numbers into one single method and call this method from each of the listeners, for example

```
void addNumbers(TextView tv1, TextView tv2, TextViev res){
   try {
       Integer val1=Integer.parseInt(value1.getText().toString());
       Integer val2=Integer.parseInt(value2.getText().toString());
       Integer answer = val1*val2;
       res.setText(answer.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) { Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Failed to multiply numbers",e);}}  
}
```

and set the onClicks to

```
multiplyButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {
        addNumbers(value1,value2,result);
        calculateResultSum();
});
```

with the corresponding views for each Button. Hope I could help.

Comment: thanks.i'm trying to work through your suggested solution for having one single method for the multiplications.  Being a novice and all, it's not all that easy. Anyway, i'll let you know if it helps.  One question, though. You say calling the calculateSum method at the end of each onClick method...i'd like to have it separately such that results are produced for each multiplied pair separately, then ultimately, a separate button that adds all the results...  please see the question,i edited it and added more details on that.  Thanks for taking your time to try and help.

Comment: if you want to trigger the final calculation with a separate button just don't call the `calculateResultSum()` method at the end of each onClick, but add it to the onClick of the new button.
I guess there is not much out there about arithmetic on Android, as it is not an Android specific problem. Here is a short intro to math in Java http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-KZ9EZvNdms and if you are looking for more specific applications (say logrithms) check the java.Math package http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.calc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final EditText num1_edt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.num1_edt);
        final EditText num2_edt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.num2_edt);
        final Button add_btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.add_btn);
        findViewById(R.id.sub_btn);
        findViewById(R.id.mul_btn);
        findViewById(R.id.div_btn);
        add_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int a=Integer.parseInt(num1_edt.getText().toString());              
                int b=Integer.parseInt(num2_edt.getText().toString());
                Integer  n=a*b;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Your Num Is:"+n.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        });

    }

}
```